# Dudas sobre J2EE

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar en la plataforma *J2EE*, y me han surgido una serie de dudas, quisiera una **respuesta  menos técnica** que en la documentación que *Oracle* ofrece.

Como selección de entorno de desarrollo estoy utilizando **NetBeans**, por sus numerosos *wizards*, para desarrollar código y como servidor de aplicaciones estoy usando **Jboss**.

La duda que tengo es sobre el tema de **seguridad en aplicaciones J2EE**. He leído que este tema es "delegado" al servidor de aplicaciones configurando lo que en la documentación de *Jboss* llama "realms" y que existen varias configuraciones.

Vengo de programar php y normalmente siempre el tema de la seguridad era muy personalizable y flexible.

Mi duda es la siguient, ¿Se puede hacer una seguridad en base a *ACLs*, a modo de "usuarios - grupos - permisos"

Comment: Si vas a usar NetBeans te recomiendo glassfish como servidor de Java EE y a lo que mencionas con glassfish puedes hacerlo de forma gráfica el realm y obtener la configuración como desees desde ya sea ldap, archivo de texto base de datos etc

Comment: ¿glassfish funciona bien en produccion? no se donde lei que tenian el proyecto un poco abandonado los de oracle. Decidi usar Jboss por el tema de tener el mismo servidor de aplicaciones tanto en produccion como en desarrollo

Answer (score 0):

La seguridad que mencionas de JBoss es más para la parte administrativa, donde configuras parámetros de las aplicaciones contenidas.

Para ACL's en tu aplicación, puedes usar Spring Security. Seguramente hay otras alternativas y es enteramente posible que algunos contenedores ofrezcan su propia solución para este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Donde trabajo actualmente, usamos Spring Security, y te da la posibilidad de hacer lo que requieres como grupos de usuarios, etc. Respecto al servidor, usamos GlashFish el cual no hemos tenido ningún problema así que te lo recomiendo, lo único que no uso es NetBeans, yo ocupo IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Hola pues no la seguridad de servidor es utilizada también en aplicaciones ya que los realms sirven para todo y tenerlo todo integrado sólo que esta configuración al ser de servidor cada.vendedor  hace su propia implementación y con poca documentación no hay ejemplos por el internet sin embargo es la mejor ya que hay ya que te permite hacer cosas como SSO y otra cosas más entre aplicaciones son embargo nada te impide hacer la tuya usando filters de java

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar LDAP.

P.e. ver esto:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LDAPSecurityRealmExamples

Te puedes hacer un LDAP de pruebas con "apache directory studio" y "apache directory".

http://directory.apache.org/studio/